# In Slab Duct Work - Concrete / Cinder Block

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, ducts, slab

I have some weird and what I believe to be abnormal duct under my home. I recently installed a brand new HVAC system and it's not running or performing as desired. I believe I am losing a ton of efficiency due to this duct work being concrete and cinderblock. It looks to be sealed from the few pictures i could get after removing the furnace. HVAC installers said they hadn't seen this before. Now that I am using the system my in home temp rarely reaches the desired temp, and in the 100 degree heat it's only getting about 20 degrees coo[image]ler inside, 23 degrees cooler at most. I expected this system to get my house to 68 degrees no matter how hot it was outside! Does anyone know if there is any spray/easily installable coating that can be applied over the concrete/cinder block to help seal/insulate this duct. My coil temp has air at 44 degrees, yet by the time it flows through the ground back out of my vent's its up to mid 60 degrees. Losing 20 degrees in the short span underneath my house seems like a ton to me. Is it normal, or is this due to bad duct work? and do I have an option? Please Help! I am at a complete loss!

Comment: Is your furnace pumping air directly into this "ductwork"? Is this considered your "trunk"? How big is this space? It appears to be 24"x24"?

Comment: What part of the country are you in?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I am in Albuquerque New Mexico. Yes the air is pumped directly into this ductwork, which I imagine is exactly what you measure at about 24x24. Unfortunately the new unit is now on this opening, and I have no access to it other than floor vents! I think I'm just pretty screwed. Velocity of air can't be good as this opening is so huge, and losing 20 degress in an extremely short distance seems a lot but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: How big are the floor vents

Comment: 24x24 would suit a 4,700 square foot house. However, assuming all of your registers are sized properly then that space will simply fill with conditioned air until it pressurizes and it will be pushed through the vents at the correct velocity. You likely have to wait longer than normal to get conditioned air in your vents but it should be the correct temperature.

Comment: @JACK the about 15 x 3 inches

Comment: @MonkeyZeus my house is a whopping 1290 sq. Feet! Lol. Quote to spray sealant was 5 to 7 grand! :(

Comment: Do you have an attic?

Comment: @jack noni dont! No crawl space, nothing. Literally , the only access is through the vents or pop the furnace / unit back out. These pics were taken after taking old one out before installing new one!

Comment: Are all the registers served by this duct, or are there other supply ducts as well?  Can you crawl all the way down the duct or does it branch off into smaller lines that you can't get into?

Comment: @Mark41 I'm not sure to be honest. Going to have to have someone come scope the whole thing to see!

Comment: A spray sealant quote for 5-7 grand? I believe it. If you wanted proper ductwork then it would likely reach 15-20 grand. It's probably cheaper to get a more powerful blower installed that can withstand high static pressure along with an oversized A/C unit to make up for the "duct" inefficiencies but then you'll have high operating costs. At least you'd be comfortable though =)

Comment: Is the air temp coming from your registers 20°F colder than your indoor temperature?

Comment: @ MonkeyZeus Yea, def not doing proper ductwork. I plan to keep the house as a rental, but don't expect to be in it more than 3 or 4 more years. I'm going to have everything scoped, get a layout, see if maybe we can tell where an entry to a crawl space is/was when they scope. Then just going in with some rigid foam board and going to get it placed all around to hopfefully seal, insulate, and decrease the area. That's of course hoping that i can find access. If not I guess I'll just make access! Next time I buy a home, I'll be sure to get it scoped first! Was a broke kid when i bought it.

Comment: Yea, it's coming out 20 decrees colder. I think you or whoever said there was a velocity issue was right. That space under the house is huge, I am thinking the temperature isn't so much the issue as the amount of air actually getting pushed through vs what's getting wasted under there. Thank you for all of your knowledge and input. Much Appreciated!

Comment: Yes, my answer discussed velocity issues so if you found my answer useful then please feel free to mark it as accepted =)

Answer (score 2):

If the air coming out of your registers is about 20°F colder than the temperature of your home then things are operating properly.

See https://iwae.com/resources/videos/cold-air-conditioner-ask-expert-episode-69.html

**However**, if the volume of air coming out of the registers supplied by this cinder block ductwork is considerably less than comparable registers then you have a turbulence issue affecting air velocity most likely triggered by that corrugated "ceiling".

You should get a static pressure test done which compares the pressure of your main supply versus your main return. Any HVAC technician worth their salt will be able to tell you exactly what the problem is. However, the installer was probably just a laborer so their inexperience can be ignored.

I think fixing the corrugated ceiling will be more beneficial than sealing the cinder block.

Although, if you're already working inside the tunnel then might as well get the wall surfaces as smooth as possible too. I'm not sure which products will provide a long term solution but also not be hazardous to your breathing health even after fully cured.

Comment: Using the ground for environmental temp stabilization is actually a very old method and trying to further cool may not be as efficient. 20 degree that sounds good to me also but if the op wants cooler faster mini split may be the better way to go or insulate the duct and loose the natural stabilization that a duct in earth provides.

Comment: @EdBeal Looking at all that "natural" dust I'm starting to think the inventors of that very old method really hated their client's lungs: dust, radon, literal dirt, etc...

Comment: I guess you haven’t looked at many modern ducts. Believe it or not there are quite a few home owners that do not realize they need to change there furnace filter and do so only after things quit working.

Comment: This looks like it was  the space where fibreboard ductwork, flexduct or metal pipe ducts **should've** been, instead of airflow going into an unsealed space.

Comment: @EdBeal Oh don't worry, I believe it. However, just because the homeowner is likely to neglect their system does not warrant the original installer to be so irresponsible of OP's duct system; it's a surefire way to get radon directly to where it's needed least. However, I wouldn't doubt that OP's situation was contrived by a homeowner ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @monkeyzeus geo stabilized was really big in the 60’s & 70’s. I don’t remember radon being an issue back then and in my area it is rare but in the mountains it is more common. Ducts were intentionally built just like this in moderate climates or in my area there were government kickbacks for these systems in the 70’s and many higher end contractors installed them I don’t remember them in the smaller homes but larger ranch style, remember Frank loyd Wright was famous for concrete buildings from an earlier time so it may not be diy at all but prior to modern central air cooling.